# Where to put context.xml with Eclipse WTP?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-wtp

I'm using *Eclipse Indigo 3.7 + WTP + m2e (including m2e-wtp)*. I've configured my Tomcat 7.0 server on Eclipse. I have a web application that I'm trying to run on Tomcat through Eclipse, but when I run it, the `context.xml` file is not copied to the `conf/Catalina/localhost` directory and this causes some issues to my app.

Where the `context.xml` should be put in order to be copied to this directory?

Thanks

Comment: See this http://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_Tomcat_FAQ#How_do_I_specify_the_Tomcat_context_configuration_for_my_Web_Application.3F

Comment: @tostao Thx, I've already read this wiki but I don't see how it answers my question.

Comment: I've edited the wiki page linked by @tostao to add the missing info

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you need to specify a context.xml file when deploying a WAR file to Tomcat, then it must be included within the WAR. The simplest way to achieve this is by adding it to your webapp resources:

```
src
|_ main
   |_ webapp
      |_ META-INF
         |_ context.xml
```

When You will build your web app (*.war) maven will join it to WAR in suitable place.